# Different looking objects

Tags: interface

Just a quick question. why do all professional YouTubers have this different look of blender objects.

for example:(screenshot from a tutourial by ducky 3d)
[image]

while mine looks like:
[image]

I'm talking about that hard look and white border that looks like bevel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the *Cavity* option in the *Viewport Shading* panel:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but what exactly does it do other than that??

Comment: nothing, it just makes your object look different if you think that it's more convenient